# Variable inaccessible?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, modifiers

In the code below the variable 'id' is inaccessible in the class Horse, is this an inheritance issue? An access modifiers issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class Animal
{
private:
   int id;
};

class Horse : public Animal
{
public:
   Horse(){
      if((id % 2) == 1) { id++ };
   } 
};
```

Comment: You do realize `id` is `private`, right? You do know what `private` meas, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class `Horse` only inherits public and protected elements in this case if you use:

```
class Horse : public Animal
```

to inherit `id`, you can define this private element in `Animal` class as protected:

```
class Animal
{
protected:
  int id;
};
```

Comment: Cheers mate, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `id` to be `protected` and not `private`, then.  Or better, use the accessor you wrote...

Answer (score 0):

`id` is private to `Animal` and therefore inaccessible to `Horse`. A satisfactory design would be to access `id` through `getID()`, though you'd need a setter as well as the existing getter method.

Answer (score 0):

declaring a variable as private will give a result that only the class the variable is declared in can access it, if you want classes that inherit basic classes to be able to also access the variable, use protected.